# Meaning of franchising (Dostoevsky's The Idiot)

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of franchising in the following sentence:

> Wasted your money franchising the letter for nothing.

[https://archive.org/stream/MajorNovels/69%20The%20Idiot_djvu.txt#:~:text=Wasted%20%20your%20%20money%20%20franchising%20%20the%20%20letter%20%20for%20%20nothing](https://archive.org/stream/MajorNovels/69%20The%20Idiot_djvu.txt#:%7E:text=Wasted%20%20your%20%20money%20%20franchising%20%20the%20%20letter%20%20for%20%20nothing)

This is from the P&V translation of Dostoevsky's The Idiot. The only word I can think of that would make sense here is "Send". None of the definitions from Franchise seem to come close to that: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/franchise.

Comment: Is this a mistranslation? Or simply a typo? Shouldn't it be *franking*? From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frank): *Frank: 1 c
: to affix to (mail) a stamp or a marking indicating the payment of postage*

Comment: And indeed, [the Eva Martin translation](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2638/2638-h/2638-h.htm) reads "you spent your postage for nothing, then." So the Russian word for *frank* must have ended up as *franchise*, for some mysterious reason. The words *frank* and *franchise* come from the same French word (*franchir*), so maybe they're similar or the same in Russian ... hopefully somebody who speaks Russian can tell us.

Comment: @PeterShor hm, ok thank you very much for the feedback! Do you think it's a typo in the translation then?

Comment: @PeterShor by the way, here's my copy of it: https://gyazo.com/7983ec04fd8cf8519f3d79dfe9e83846.

Comment: *Franchising* means *setting free* here. So, yes, *sending*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat: Is that what the Russian means?

Comment: @PeterShor — Ah, I see what you mean now. Back later with more on the definition of *frank* in that era.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be a typo or a mistranslation. The word should probably be
*franking*, one of whose definitions (from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frank)) is:

> 1 c : to affix to (mail) a stamp or a marking indicating the payment of postage

The Russian text is (found by looking at a parallel Russian-English version online:

> Даром деньги на франкировку письма истратили.

DeepL translates this as:

> The money for franking the letter was wasted.

Comment: great answer, thanks so much. By the way, are you able to read Russian yourself? If so, how would you personally translate that sentence?

Comment: I can't read Russian ... the only way I found the appropriate sentence was looking at a version with parallel Russian-English text I found on the web.